# One Google Script won't authorise, the others will

Tags: google-apps-script

We have changed our Google password recently, and re-authorised all our scripts except for this one.

This one script is the only one that will not authorise.  Running it from the editor doesn't ask for authorisation, but executing the web app still shows the "You must provide authorisation for this app to run" error.

I'm providing the link, please let me know what else I can do.

https://script.google.com/d/1Cb90JPvS2gDn1invg1f4NKErn7urfhJm0vmrkNsjW0trVvHj0NBO8sNK/edit?usp=drive_web

Here is the code below.  It takes out "shows" that have passed and puts them in a monthly spreadsheet (for each month) removing them from the working spreadsheet, as the other google scripts become slow when the working spreadsheet has too many rows in it.  (It also relies on another script called "Global").

```
var MAX_PROCESSED = 100;

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var start_screen = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var wait_screen = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("screen");

  var gig_sheet = Global.getGigsSheet();
  var max_rows = gig_sheet.getLastRow();
  var max_cols = gig_sheet.getLastColumn();
  var col_descriptions = gig_sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, max_cols).getValues()[0];
  var col_ids = gig_sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, max_cols).getValues()[0];

  var cur_date = new Date();
  var archive_filename = "Database archive "+cur_date.toDateString();
  var old_file = SpreadsheetApp.create(archive_filename, 0, max_cols);
  var old_sheet = old_file.getActiveSheet();
  old_file.renameActiveSheet("Database");
  old_sheet.appendRow(col_descriptions);
  old_sheet.appendRow(col_ids);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var message = (max_rows-2)+ " gigs to examine. ";
  if(max_cols > 500)
    message+= "Hmm... This may take a while. ";

  message+="<br/>New archive database ready \""+archive_filename+"\".  Press start to begin.";

  var id_string = old_file.getId();
  Global.log("doc id:"+id_string);
  var doc_id_widget = app.createHidden("doc_id", id_string);
  var row_pos_widget = app.createHidden("row_pos", 3);
  var old_total_widget = app.createHidden("old_total", max_rows);

  var start_button = app.createButton("Start");
  start_button.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(start_screen).setVisible(false).forTargets(wait_screen).setVisible(true));
  start_button.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('processGigs').addCallbackElement(doc_id_widget).addCallbackElement(row_pos_widget).addCallbackElement(old_total_widget));

  start_screen.add(app.createHTML(message));
  start_screen.add(start_button);

  wait_screen.add(app.createHTML("Working... should take about 60 seconds.  If it goes longer than 6 minutes, Google will display an error anyway."));
  wait_screen.setVisible(false);

  app.add(start_screen);
  app.add(wait_screen);

  return app;
}

function test()
{
  var test;
}

function processGigs(e){

  Global.log("processGigs");
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var row_pos = parseInt(e.parameter.row_pos);
  var id_string = e.parameter.doc_id;
  var old_total = e.parameter.old_total;
  var screen = app.getElementById("screen");
  screen.setVisible(false);

  Global.log("Loading row_pos:"+row_pos+", raw data:"+e.parameter.row_pos);
  Global.log("Spreadsheet ID:"+id_string);

  var gig_sheet = Global.getGigsSheet();
  var max_rows = gig_sheet.getLastRow();
  var max_cols = gig_sheet.getLastColumn();
  var col_descriptions = gig_sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, max_cols).getValues()[0];
  var col_ids = gig_sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, max_cols).getValues()[0];

  var old_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_string);
  var old_sheet = old_file.getActiveSheet();

  var cur_date = new Date();
  var existing_date;
  var existing_fee;

  var archive_count= 0;
  var row;
  var range;
  var item;
  var items_processed = 0;

  while (items_processed < MAX_PROCESSED && row_pos <= max_rows){
    Global.log("row_pos:"+row_pos+", max_rows:"+max_rows+", max_cols:"+max_cols);
    range = gig_sheet.getRange(row_pos, 1, 1, max_cols);
    row = range.getValues()[0];
    item = Global.arrayToObject(col_ids, row, false);
    Global.parseValuesOnObject(col_ids, item, false);
    if((item.paid >= item.fee && item.date < cur_date) || item.status == "Cancelled"){
      old_sheet.appendRow(row);
      gig_sheet.deleteRows(row_pos,1);
      max_rows--;
      archive_count++;
    }else{
      row_pos++;
    }
    items_processed++;
  }

  var work_screen = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var wait_screen = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("screen").setVisible(false);
  var message_widget = app.createHTML();
  work_screen.add(message_widget);
  wait_screen.add(app.createHTML("Working... should take about 60 seconds.  If it goes longer than 6 minutes, Google will display an error anyway."));


  Global.log("Saving row_pos:"+row_pos);
  var doc_id_widget = app.createHidden("doc_id", id_string);
  var row_pos_widget = app.createHidden("row_pos", row_pos);
  var old_total_widget = app.createHidden("old_total", old_total);

  var start_button = app.createButton("Continue");
  start_button.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(work_screen).setVisible(false).forTargets(wait_screen).setVisible(true));
  start_button.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('processGigs').addCallbackElement(doc_id_widget).addCallbackElement(row_pos_widget).addCallbackElement(old_total_widget));

  //new_sheet.getRange(1, new_data.length, 1, new_data[0].length).setValues(new_data);
  //old_sheet.getRange(1, old_data.length, 1, old_data[0].length).setValues(old_data);
  var message = archive_count + " gigs archived.</br>";
  if(row_pos < max_rows){
    message += "Process limit reached. "+(max_rows - row_pos)+" to go, so click Continue to keep trying.";
    work_screen.add(start_button);
  }else{
    message += "End of records reached, none left to archive.  You can close this window now.";
  }

  //message +="<br/>row_pos:"+row_pos+", max_rows:"+max_rows;
  message_widget.setHTML(message);

  app.add(work_screen);
  app.add(wait_screen);

  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I don't like scripts relying much on other scripts and would try to keep them together. Double check if the dependency script authorises and runs correctly.

The other thing I can think of is to go [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1), find the script (the older version is probably authorised) and remove it. Otherwise, I don't think there is not enough information to provide a more in-depth answer if this does not help.

Comment: I want to thank you for helping.  At the very least I didn't realise that page exists.  In delving into this again I actually worked out the issue, it was to do with who had ownership of the file. I posted my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I worked it out.  Because we were jumping between accounts, this one script had a different "owner" than the rest.  So now both that owner and the account we want to run it from, need to authorise it before the published version works...

I finally though to check when I noticed when publishing, there is a notice that says "The previous owner needs to authorise before publishing the URL" or something.